# Facebook API get subsribers of a page?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've been searching the Graph API Explorer and documentation for a long time, but I really can't find anything.

I need a simple GET request like the me/subscribes just with page-id/subscribers or something like that. Does anyone know the get I must send to get a Count of subscribers of a page?

BTW I'm using Facebook SDK and I'm using this as GET:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(useraccesstoken);
dynamic result = fb.Get("i want to get subscribers of a page id what to do??");
```

Comment: there are no subscribers for a page, there are fans. and you cannot just get the list of them.

Comment: Yea you can get a Count of fans if you dont know, when you do get page-id there is a thing called likes which is a total Count of likes you can e.g. achieve it like this:                     dynamic result = fb.Get(pageid);
string likes = Convert.ToString(result.likes);

Anyways there is somehting called subscribers or followers on a page. Is there anyway to get a total Count of them? Not their names just a number which says how many subscribers/followers you have.
Picture of the subscribers im talking about: http://i.imgur.com/GljBXS9.png

Comment: it´s not in the graph api call for a page, so i doubt that it is possible

Comment: Thats what i thought too, but maybe some people found a way to Count it another way or something. But thanks for the answer anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `/me/subscribers` end-point was available to users' only, and has since been removed with Graph API 2.0, along with the `user_subscriptions` permission.

You can get a count of the subscribers / likes for a page as follows:

```
/{page-id}?fields=likes
```

This will return an a count for the total number of likes for a given `{page-id}`:

```
{
  "likes": 123456, 
  "id": "{page-id}"
}
```

Trying to access the subscribers of a page is the same as trying to access all the users that have liked the page, which Facebook doesn't allow.